# What is the reason for a joinable std::thread not join automatically?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, language-lawyer

Sometimes it would be useful if a joinable `std::thread` had the hability to execute `thread::join()` on its destructor. See the examples below.

**Example 1 (error):**
The object `std::thread` has been destroyed after the throw of the exception. Once the the flow exits the scope, the destructor is called BEFORE the join happens. It makes STL show an error message of 'abort'.

```
int main( int argc, const char * argv[] )
{
    try
    {
        thread t( [] ()
        {
            this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::seconds( 1 ) );
            cout << "thread done" << endl;
        } );

        throw exception( "some exception" );

        t.join();
    }
    catch ( const exception & )
    {
        cout << "exception caught!" << endl;
    }

    cout << "main done" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Example 2 (correct way):**
The object `t` is created before my try-catch block and the join() is put on both try and catch blocks. So it guarantees that the join() happens.

```
int main( int argc, const char * argv[] )
{
    thread t;

    try
    {
        t = thread( [] ()
        {
            this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::seconds( 1 ) );
            cout << "thread done" << endl;
        } );

        throw exception( "some exception" );

        t.join( );
    }
    catch ( const exception & )
    {
        t.join();
        cout << "exception caught!" << endl;
    }

    cout << "main done" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**...AND THE QUESTION IS:**
What is the reason for a joinable `std::thread` not join automatically on its destructor?

It would be much easier if it happened automatically. The way it's done today requires one must be careful when using threads inside try-catch blocks, for example... but I am sure someone THOUGHT when designed `std::thread` this way. So there must be a reason for that... what is that reason?

**PS:** I know we can envolve `std::thread` in a class and put the `join()` on the destructor of this new class... so it becomes automatic. But this is not the point. My question is really about `std::thread` itself.

Comment: Separation of concerns. If you want a thing that starts a thread and waits for its completion on destruction, write it.

Comment: Note that your code above doesn't guarantee that `join()` happens.  In C++ you can throw a value of any type - it doesn't have to derive from `std::exception`.  In C++, if you need to guarantee that some action happens (whether an exception is thrown or not), use an RAII handle where the cleanup occurs in the destructor.

Comment: about this, ok, I assumed the throwing of std::exception only. but I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason is simply so that you are forced to think about it. If a `std::thread` object is destroyed due to an exception escaping the scope then a join may cause a blocking wait during stack unwinding, which is often undesirable, and can lead to deadlock if the thread that is being waited for is in turn waiting for some action on the part of the thread doing the waiting.

By having the application terminate in this situation you as a programmer are forced to actively think about the conditions that would cause the object to be destroyed, and ensure that the thread is joined correctly.

Comment: Yeah - sounds like a perfect recipie for shutdown failures.

Comment: "If a std::thread object is destroyed due to an exception escaping the scope then a join may cause a blocking wait during stack unwinding" - I don't understand: if an std::thread object is already destroyed, how could anything else call join on it? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Anthony Williams Why the program still crashes if there is no `t.join()` in `catch` block.For details, see https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fcffbee96d4218b.

Comment: Anything between a `throw` and the corresponding `catch` is ignored, so your call to `t.join()` is never executed. If you put it before the `throw`, *then* it is executed.