# Why std::make_unique<std::thread>(somefun()) will generate crash when I haven't call release(), and well when called?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

My code:

```
{
    t = std::make_unique<std::thread>(std::bind(&Widget::generateNum, this));
}
```

crash at `~thread()` , error msg is '**r6010 abort() has been called**'. If I haven't call `t.release()` before that destructing `t`, will cause the crash.

Comment: Post the rest of the code. Something might be going out of scope.

Comment: The code you have shown isn't enough to determine the problem.

Comment: @dreamlax: Actually, not true.

Comment: For those closing as "off-topic: why isn't this code working" I would like to point out that the code snippet will call `abort` as written, if you just add dummy definitions to make things compile and let `t` go out of scope. The only valid close reason for this question is "duplicate", but I wasn't able to find a duplicate question. I'm sure there is one.

Comment: almost a duplicate (concerns pre-Standard `thread` class): https://stackoverflow.com/q/21502565/103167

Comment: another near-dupe that explains why it works this way: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21334406/103167

Comment: @Dietrich: This one looks like a duplicate, even involves unique_ptr: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25911734/103167

Comment: I don't think my problem is dupe because my question related to `unique_ptr<T>::release()`.

Comment: and another: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7406596/103167

Comment: @Crawl.W: `make_unique` is not a type, it's a function that returns `unique_ptr<T>`.  And the link you replied to DOES call `std::unique_ptr<std::thread>::release()`.

Comment: @BenVoigt slip of a pen, lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must detach or join a thread before destroying it.

```
auto t = std::make_unique<std::thread>(std::bind(&Widget::generateNum, this));

// Either do this:
t->detach();
// or do this:
t->join();
// before *t gets destroyed.
```

The choice of whether to detach or join is up to you, but you *must* do one or the other. If a non-empty `std::thread` gets destroyed it will call `std::terminate`, ending your program.

See [std::thread::~thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread):

> If `*this` has an associated thread (`joinable() == true`), `std::terminate()` is called.

The default `std::terminate` handler calls `std::abort`, hence the message that abort has been called.

## Don't Call t.release()

It would be a mistake to call `t.release()`.  This would leak the `std::thread` object.

Comment: What you referred to is the cause of the crash and I know.But why 't.release()' will done well?

Comment: Calling `t.release()` will leak the `std::thread` object. This avoids calling the destructor entirely, and leaks memory. Do not do this.

Comment: While it's technically true that either joining or detaching the thread will eliminate this crash, detaching is almost never the right answer, especially for beginners. It's an advanced tool.

Comment: @PeteBecker: In my experience, `.detach()` is not exceptional--and often `.join()` is just a poor substitute for `std::async`. Calling it an "advanced tool" is a matter of pedagogical opinion.